# Spray-json JsNumber BigDecimal isValid* strangeness

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

Can somebody explain this to me:

```
scala> import spray.json._

import spray.json._



scala> import DefaultJsonProtocol._

import DefaultJsonProtocol._


scala> def check(n: BigDecimal) = {

     |     println(s"n.isValidByte = ${n.isValidByte}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidChar = ${n.isValidChar}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidDouble = ${n.isValidDouble}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidFloat = ${n.isValidFloat}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidInt = ${n.isValidInt}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidLong = ${n.isValidLong}")

     |     println(s"n.isValidShort = ${n.isValidShort}")

     | }

check: (n: BigDecimal)Unit

scala> check(JsNumber(0.16) match { case JsNumber(x) => x})

n.isValidByte = false

n.isValidChar = false

n.isValidDouble = false

n.isValidFloat = false

n.isValidInt = false

n.isValidLong = false

n.isValidShort = false
```

I am using the spray-json 1.2.6, with Scala 2.10.3 and these are my libraryDependencies:

> "io.spray" %% "spray-json"          % "1.2.6"

Thanks,
Grega

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the conversion from BigDecimal to float is not perfect so it returns false.  The floatValue must do some rounding.  Observe:

```
BigDecimal(.16).floatValue                      //> res8: Float = 0.16
```

But when you try to convert BigDecimal -> Float -> BigDecimal you see the rounding error:

```
BigDecimal(BigDecimal(.16).floatValue)          //> res8: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.1599999964237213
```

If you chose a different value that can be exactly expressed in powers of 2 then your check function would work:

```
  BigDecimal(BigDecimal(.5).floatValue)           //> res10: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.5
  BigDecimal(.5).isValidFloat                     //> res11: Boolean = true
```

**TLDR** BigDecimal does arbitrary decimals well, float stores in powers of two so instead of 0.16 the best it can do is get very close 0.1599999964237213 but since there is some loss isValidFloat returns false.